# How do I find the location of the source of a man page?

Tags: files, man

I'd like to pipe a *raw* manual page, in *roff format, into `pandoc` to convert it to PDF and show it in a document viewer, e.g.,

```
$ my_script vim
...
```

to have a new window showing the formatted man page.

I have no other problem writing `my_script`, the bulk of it would be something like

```
zcat /???/vim.?.gz | pandoc -f man -t pdf | okular -
```

but I don't know how to find the exact location of the *roff source of the vim man page, except that is somewhere in a sub–directory of `$MANPATH`.

I'm aware that some commands have multiple man pages, so I'd like to know how can I retrieve the *first location* of a man page source.

Comment: Note that the `mandb`  `man` program which is common on Linux can output PDFs, so: `man -Tpdf vim | okular -`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By reading `man man`, you'll see`man`'s `-w` option:

```
-w, --where, --path, --location
       Don't actually display the manual page, but do print the
       location of the source nroff file that would be formatted.
       If the -a option is also used, then print the locations of
       all source files that match the search criteria.
```

Comment: Come on, you know this — the right approach here isn’t to add an answer!